# Hi what's the syntax to separate this database, using spaces as the delimiter

Tags: sql, t-sql, data-analysis

I just started learning SQL and basically doing data analysis. I downloaded this dataset from Kaggle and on importing all the data has merged into one column and I've to separate it so I can clean it and do some analysis on it.

[image]

I've tried using `CHARINDEX` but to no avail

```
SELECT 
    LEFT(ID_Year_Birth_Education_Marital_Status_Income_Kidhome_Teenhome_D, 
        CHARINDEX(' ', ID_Year_Birth_Education_Marital_Status_Income_Kidhome_Teenhome_D)) 
FROM 
    [dbo].[marketing_campaign$]
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: I'd go back to the original data set and do the import again, changing the parameters to get the correct result.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. An image of data doesn't help us help you, nor does expecting us to analyze the image and intuit the results you might want. Sample data in a usable format and expected results make it much easier. Including DDL means we don't even have to guess at data types.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be best if you would just try to import that file again, but to a proper table with more than that weird column.

But to answer the question.

Here's some test code that works in Sql Server 2017

**Setup test data**

> ```
> create table bad_import (
> id int identity(1,1) primary key,
> ID_Year_Birth_Education_Marital_Status_Income_Kidhome_Teenhome_D varchar(300) not null
> );
>
>
> insert into bad_import (ID_Year_Birth_Education_Marital_Status_Income_Kidhome_Teenhome_D) 
> values
>   ('100 1969 Basic Married 99999 1 1 25-12-2020 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11')
> , ('200 1972 PhD Single 12345 0 0 12-06-2021 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from bad_import
> ```
>
> ```
> id | ID_Year_Birth_Education_Marital_Status_Income_Kidhome_Teenhome_D   
> -: | :------------------------------------------------------------------
>  1 | 100 1969 Basic Married 99999 1 1 25-12-2020 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
>  2 | 200 1972 PhD Single 12345 0 0 12-06-2021 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
> ```

**Creating a temporary table**

> ```
> create table #tmp_targets (
>  ID int primary key, 
>  Year_Birth decimal(4,0), 
>  Education varchar(30), 
>  Marital_Status varchar(30), 
>  Income int, 
>  Kidhome int, 
>  Teenhome int, 
>  Dt date
> )
> ```

**Transforming the data and insert fields into the temp table**

> ```
> with DATA (txt) as (
>   select ID_Year_Birth_Education_Marital_Status_Income_Kidhome_Teenhome_D txt
>   from bad_import
> )
> , UNFOLDED as (
>   select 
>   cast(left(txt, charindex(' ', txt)) as int) AS ID
>   , ca.*
>   from DATA d 
>   cross apply (
>      select value 
>      , row_number() over (order by (select null)) as rn
>      from string_split(txt, ' ')
>   ) ca
> ) 
> insert into #tmp_targets 
> (ID, Year_Birth, Education, Marital_Status, 
>  Income, Kidhome, Teenhome, Dt)
> select ID
> , cast([2] as decimal(4,0)) as Year_Birth
> , [3] as Education
> , [4] as Marital_Status
> , cast([5] as int) as Income
> , cast([6] as int) as Kidhome
> , cast([7] as int) as Teenhome
> , convert(date, [8], 105) as Dt
> from UNFOLDED
> pivot (
>  max(value) 
>  for rn in ([2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8])
> ) pvt;
> ```

**Query the temporary table:**

> ```
> select *
> from #tmp_targets
> order by ID
> ```
>
> ```
>  ID | Year_Birth | Education | Marital_Status | Income | Kidhome | Teenhome | Dt        
> --: | ---------: | :-------- | :------------- | -----: | ------: | -------: | :---------
> 100 |       1969 | Basic     | Married        |  99999 |       1 |        1 | 2020-12-25
> 200 |       1972 | PhD       | Single         |  12345 |       0 |        0 | 2021-06-12
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e900d62c23215c1fc12287d0d4d0efaa)*